# How do I configure apache2 to a port other than port 80?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, port

I have installed **apache2** on **ubunto** and have messed around with the text on the localhost page. Now I'm being asked to show it running on a port other than **port 80**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line `Listen x` in your `httpd.conf` where `x` is the port number. You'll need to restart your apache server after that.

Answer (score 0):

In the file: `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

change the following line:

```
Listen 80
```

to:

```
Listen <NEWPORT>
```

After that you need to restart the apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

**UPDATE:** Looks like with Ubuntu, the default `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is empty and the recommended approach is to create a new `.conf` file under `/etc/apache2/conf.d` so that even with software updates, the user changes are persistent.

So just create a new file say `/etc/apache2/conf.d/mycustomizations.conf`

```
Listen <NEWPORT>
```